# Firestore security rules request.writeFields is deprecated

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firestore security rules request.writeFields is deprecated.

Is there any alternative?

For instance, I have three fields in document (name, email, phone number), I don't want to allow users to update phone number.

I can check this by comparing the before and after data. But if I have lot of fields in document then it is very difficult.

So if there is any alternative it will be more helpful.

Comment: There is no 1:1 replacement for `request.writeFields`. If you describe what you're trying to accomplish, we may be able to help better. Showing what you've already is also a good way to show us the context. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Now I added my context.

Comment: I believe Firebase Team will provide 1:1 replacement in future. It helps lot of developers. Now request.writeFields is working as expected, when it will stop working? Will it stop without any notice?

Comment: `request.writeFields` was removed because there were situations where it didn't work. There is currently no work being done on providing a replacement. Unless you have a concrete question on how to accomplish a specific use-case, there's not a good way to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [`request.resource.data.diff()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff):

```js
// Compare two Map objects and return whether the key "a" has been
// affected; that is, key "a" was added or removed, or its value was updated.
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["a"]);
```